# Cypress: Verify value of multiple <td> in same row on Table

Tags: html-table, cypress

I tried to verify the value in [Item] and [Status] columns based on [Class] column value as below table.

Detail is I find  contain value of 3rd  'Birds' then verify items = ['Eagle', 'Duck', 'Parrot'] and staus = 'BLue'

Here is HTML of the row I will check.

```
<tr class="animal">
        <td>
            <div>
                <i aria-hidden="true"
                   class="theme--light">
                </i>
                <input
                    aria-checked="false" role="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-truncate">
                <span>
                    Birds
                </span>
            </div>
            <span><!----></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-truncate"><span><!---->
                            Eagle , Duck , Parrot
                          </span></div>
            <span><!----></span></td>
        <td><span class="blue--text">BLue</span></td>
 </tr>
```

[image]

Here my code:

```
 verifyRowValue(class, items, status) {
    const secondTd = cy.get('table').find('tbody tr').find('td:nth-child(3)')
    const span = secondTd.find('span');
    const class= 'Birds';
    const items = ['Eagle', 'Duck', 'Parrot'];
    const staus= 'Normal';
    const type = status === 'Rare' ? 'Red' : 'BLue';

    if (span.contains(class)) {
        const tr = secondTd.closest('tr')
        //Check 4th <td>
        tr.find('td').eq(3)
            .find('span').invoke('text').then(text => {
            const spanText = text.trim();
            for (let item in items) {
                expect(spanText).to.includes(items[item])
            }
        }).then(() => {   // => Check 5th <td>
            tr.find('td').eq(4)
                .find('span').invoke('text')
                .then(selType => {
                    expect(selType).to.eq(type);
                });
        })
    }  
}
```

I run verify 4th  ok, but 5th  is failed.

Maybe I used then() in the wrong way?

Comment: What is the error log?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to use `.trim()` on column 5.

```js
.then(selType => {
  expect(selType.trim()).to.eq(type);
});
```